# python functions and mersenne number

Tags: python, function, primes

Been trying to do this in python but having errors:

1. Write a function that accepts an exponent p and returns the corresponding Mersenne number between 3 and 65
2. Write a function that accepts the exponent p of a Mersenne number and returns the Lucas-Lehmer sequence up to  i=p−2(inclusive).
3. For a given Mersenne number with exponent p, the number is prime if the Lucas-Lehmer series is 0 at position  p−2. Write a function that tests if a Mersenne number with exponent p is prime. Test if the Mersenne numbers with prime p between 3 and 65 (i.e. 3, 5, 7, ..., 61) are prime. Your final answer should be a list of tuples consisting of (Mersenne exponent, 0) (or 1) for each Mersenne number you test, where 0 and 1 are replacements for False and True respectively.

```
def is_prime(number):
    if number <= 1:
        return False
    
    for factor in range(2, number):
        if number % factor == 0:
            return False

    return True

def print_primes(n):
    for number in range(1, n):
        if is_prime(number):
            print('%d is prime' % number)
```

Comment: Please add code that you have already written.

Comment: How do I add the code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Done, take a look at it but I want to list only the prime numbers between 3 and 65

Comment: "Write a function that accepts the exponent p" - where is this function? No need to check range(2, number), can limit to range(2, math.sqrt(number))

Comment: Your code completely ignores what your assignment asks for. What do you think a Mersenne number is?

Answer (score 1):

Answer to 1st question:

```
def mersenne_number(p):
new_list = []
for number in p:
    temp = (2**number - 1)
    new_list.append(temp)
return new_list

def is_prime(number):
if number<2:
    return False

for factor in range(2, number):
    if number % factor == 0:
        return False
    
return True

def get_primes(n_start, n_end):
    my_list = []
    for number in range(n_start, n_end):
        if is_prime(number):
            my_list.append(number)
    return my_list

mersennes = mersenne_number(get_primes(3,65))
```